# Organise array as based on dates field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on a rails app with vue in front end.
I have the following data as below

```
records = [["2020-07-01", "Jamie", 66],
   ["2020-07-01", "Rob", 12],
   ["2020-08-01", "Jamie", 31],      
   ["2020-09-01", "Jamie", 46],
   ["2020-09-01", "Rob", 10],
   ["2020-10-01", "Rob", 4]]
```

I want to organise this data as

```
final_result = [{:name=>"Jamie", :data=>[66, 31, 46, 0]},
 {:name=>"Rob", :data=>[12, 0, 10, 4]}]
```

I was thinking of using .map something like records.map but I am not able to figure-out how can I combine the values in the data field

like in the final_result I have combined the values 66, 31, 46, 0 for Jamie and 12, 0, 10, 4 for Rob based on the dates: July, August, September, October.

If the value is not present in any month then it is set to 0. Please help me resolve this issue.

Update 1

Answer not working for this data set below

```
records = [
   ["2020-01-01", nil, nil, 0],
   ["2020-02-01", nil, nil, 0],
   ["2020-03-01", nil, nil, 0],
   ["2020-04-01", nil, nil, 0],
   ["2020-05-01", nil, nil, 0],
   ["2020-06-01", nil, nil, 0],
   ["2020-07-01", 2, "Jamie", 66],
   ["2020-07-01", 7, "Rob", 1],
   ["2020-08-01", 2, "Jamie", 29],
   ["2020-08-01", 7, "Rob", 2]]
```

in the case about the output should be

```
[{:name=>"Jamie", :data=>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66, 29]},
 {:name=>"Rob", :data=>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]}]
```

But according to Answer

the output is

```
[{:name=>"Jamie", :data=>[0, 0, 0, 0, nil, nil, 66, 29]},
 {:name=>"Rob", :data=>[0, 0, 0, 0, nil, nil, 1, 2]}]
```

I am not able to figure out why is it showing nil values instead of zero.

Comment: Obviously not a good answer and you should never do this in production, but if you wanted a one liner without rails (just for fun):

    `records.map { |ar| ar[1] }.uniq.map { |name| records.map(&:first).uniq.map { |date| records.any? { |arr| arr[0] == date && arr[1] == name } ? records.select { |arr| arr[0] == date && arr[1] == name }.flatten : [date, name, 0] } }.map { |arr| arr.map { |a| a[1 .. -1] } }.map { |r| r.group_by(&:first).map { |k, a| [ { name: k, date: a.map(&:last) }] } }.flatten`

Comment: @benjessop can you post this in answer?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
records = [["2020-07-01", "Jamie", 66],
   ["2020-07-01", "Rob", 12],
   ["2020-08-01", "Jamie", 31],      
   ["2020-09-01", "Jamie", 46],
   ["2020-09-01", "Rob", 10],
   ["2020-10-01", "Rob", 4]]

months = records.map { |record| Date.parse(record.first, '').month }.uniq.sort
result = []
result_hash = records.inject({}) do |memo, record|
  memo[record.second] ||= Array.new(4).map { |_| 0 }
  memo[record.second][Date.parse(record.first).month - months.first] = record.last
  memo
end
result_hash.each { |key, value|  result << { name: key, data: value }}
p result
```

=>

```
[{:name=>"Jamie", :data=>[66, 31, 46, 0]}, {:name=>"Rob", :data=>[12, 0, 10, 4]}]
```

Comment: Please check update 1 in the question. I tried your solution but it doesn't work for the case data in update 1 section